# Loki - dconf-editor not working?

Tags: settings, release-loki, dconf

In freya I used to modify wingpanel a little (e.g. having seconds show in the clock etc.) using dconf-editor.

This does not seem to work anymore in loki. I can modify the respective settings in dconf-editor, but it doesn't have any effect.

Is this a bug or a design choice?

Answer (score 1):

dconf-editor is working as it should.

Though it seems it is not posssible to change time format in wingpanel anymore using dconf-editor anymore.

[image]
On my (freshly installed) system there is only an option to show week numbers.

Also elementary-tweaks does not show an option to change the time format, see https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks.

Comment: You're right - I figured out the same after a clean install including formatting my home folder. However, I think at first try I kept my home folder data and the options were there, as in my question. Not sure anymore though. In any case I think they shouldn't have dropped options